# Closing useless areas with python

Tags: python

I want to close all useless areas in my blender window. How command I could use?

To sum up, I need the command of "Close area":

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type != 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        #Close area
```

Comment: Why you can't use: CTRL + UP? ...only to understand the issue :)

Comment: Well, because Blender isn't open. I'm using python in gedit, so, to do any change, I need to code what I want. After code, I run my script, and it creates a blender file with my specifications.

Comment: Related: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?308653-Tutorial-as-a-Python-Script (posts #4 and #12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Blender's default startup.blend as your initial starting place, the easier solution would be to change to the "3D View Full screen" layout and then change that area to hold the editor you want (in your case, the UV/Image Editor). The code might look something like this:

```
bpy.context.window.screen = bpy.data.screens['3D View Full']
bpy.context.screen.areas[0].type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
```